# Pandas: DataFrame function call returning same results for all rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with the following columns:

```
link    sqft    rent    bedroom     address1    address2    address3    bathroom
```

I have a function that takes 3 addresses as input then returns the latitude and longtitude as a `dict`.

When I apply the function like this ...

```
df['lat'] = return_coordinates(df.address1,df.address2,df.addresse3).get('Latitude')
```

... the `lat` column contains the same value.

Here's the function:

```
import herepy

geocoderApi = herepy.GeocoderApi('ap_key')
def return_coordinates(address1,address2,address3):
    response = geocoderApi.free_form('{},{},{}'.format(address1,address2,address3))
    geocode = response.as_dict()
    geocode = geocode.get('Response')
    geocode = geocode.get('View')
    value =  (geocode[0].get('Result')[0].get('Location').get('DisplayPosition'))
    return value
```

Comment: post more code. Few lines of data and expected result

Comment: Try using DataFrame's [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function and pass your `return_coordinates` function into it.  This will broadcast the results of each set of coordinates to your `lat` column.

Comment: @s3dev I don't know how to do that, since the output is based on other columns of the dataset.

Comment: @KaziAbuJaforJaber: See my answer below.  Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the **`DataFrame.apply()`** function.  [Documentation can be found here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

I've faked you're dataset, albeit poorly, due to a lack of data and access to your API.  But this demonstrates how you can use the `apply()` function to populate your `lat` column from your function's return value(s).

#### Basic (hacked) setup:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'link': ['www.abc.com/1', 'www.abc.com/2', 'www.abc.com/3'],
        'sqft': [1111, 2222, 3333],
        'rent': ['$1111', '$2222', '$3333'],
        'bedroom': [1, 2, 3],
        'address1': [[34.052235, -118.243683], [33.052235, -117.243683], [32.052235, -115.243683]],
        'address2': [[32.715736, -117.161087], [31.715736, -116.161087], [30.715736, -115.161087]],
        'address3': [[33.541679, -117.777214], [32.541679, -116.777214], [31.541679, -115.777214]],
        'bathroom': [1, 2, 3]}

# Create dataset
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def return_coordinates(address1, address2, address3):
    """Return the first value of the ``address1`` parameter."""
    return address1[0]
```

#### Use the `apply` function:

This will broadcast the return of your `return_coordinates` function to your DataFrame's `lat` column.

```
df['lat'] = df.apply(lambda x: return_coordinates(x['address1'], x['address2'], x['address3']), axis=1)
```

#### Original dataset:

```
    address1    address2    address3    bathroom    bedroom     link    rent    sqft
0   [34.052235, -118.243683]    [32.715736, -117.161087]    [33.541679, -117.777214]    1   1   www.abc.com/1   $1111   1111
1   [33.052235, -117.243683]    [31.715736, -116.161087]    [32.541679, -116.777214]    2   2   www.abc.com/2   $2222   2222
2   [32.052235, -115.243683]    [30.715736, -115.161087]    [31.541679, -115.777214]    3   3   www.abc.com/3   $3333   3333
```

#### With the new `lat` column:

```
address1    ...     lat
0   [34.052235, -118.243683]    ...     34.052235
1   [33.052235, -117.243683]    ...     33.052235
2   [32.052235, -115.243683]    ...     32.052235
```

As you can see in the results, the `apply` function returns the first value of the `address1` field, for each row.

Comment: Seem's like it would work with a little adjustment's, I'll be right back after I see If I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. Here is an example of what you are looking for, just in case :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'address1': [1, 2, 3], 'address2': [4, 5, 6], 'address3': [7, 8, 9]})

def return_coordinates(a,b,c):
    d = {
        "Latitude": a+b+c,
        "Longitude": a*b*c
    }
    return d

df['lat'] = return_coordinates(df['address1'], df['address2'], df['address3']).get("Latitude")
df['lng'] = return_coordinates(df['address1'], df['address2'], df['address3']).get("Longitude")
print(df)
```

Output :

```
   address1  address2  address3  lat  lng
0         1         4         7   12   28
1         2         5         8   15   80
2         3         6         9   18  162
```

Comment: df['lat'] = rc(df['address1'],df['address2'],df['address3']).get('Latitude')
df['lng'] = rc(df['address1'],df['address2'],df['address3']).get('Longitude')   - Doesn't work Same problme

Comment: I edited my answer. Is it still not the same problem ?

Comment: Yep, same problem, every row in lat and lng column is the same

Comment: maybe try to put the line `geocoderApi = herepy.GeocoderApi('ap_key')` inside your `return_coordinates` function

Comment: No luck, It work when I do something like addition, but doesn't work in any other columns

Comment: weird problem ^^. Maybe you could check the type of `value` and see if it's an immutable item